# Filer DataTable to exclude DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I receive a DataTable from excel file and data in the first Column looks like this:

`11129`

`DBNull.Value`

`29299`

`29020`

`DBNull.Value`

`29020`

I'm using LINQ to select distict and it works if there are no DBNull.Value values as below.

```
albumIds = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(p => (int)p.Field<double>("F1")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

But if `DBNull.Value` present which represent empty excel cells I get conversion errors.

How do I filter out those `DBNull.Value` from my result set?

Thank you

Comment: How are you getting the data from excel to a datatable? Is there more than one column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted at in Jeremy's answer, If you've a reference to [System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx), you'll get some handy extension methods for working with DataSets and DataTables using LINQ. Specifically, you can use the Field`<int?>`() method to convert an integer column that might contain DBNull into a column of nullable ints...

```
albumIds = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int?>("F1"))
                            .Where(val => val.HasValue)
                            .Select(val => val.Value)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.IsNull("F1") == false)
  .Select(p => p.Field<int>("F1")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

I can't really check this as I don't have this DB setup

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the null values out first. Then your LINQ expression should work great.

Comment: Yea so how do I filter out Null values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the fields for DBNull before you attempt the conversion using the Where method is probably easiest.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Field("F1") != DBNull.Value).Select(p => (int)p.Field("F1")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: this won't work because with Field Extension you need to specify a type Field<T>

Answer (score -1):

I'll answer my own question.

Instead of using Linq I do a foreach loop and delete rows if value is null. 
and then do Linq distinct

```
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["F1"].ToString()))
                    row.Delete();
            }

            dt.AcceptChanges();

            albumIds = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(p => (int)p.Field<double>("F1")).Distinct().ToArray();
```