# Fill an array (or arraylist) from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there a way to fill an array via a SqlDataReader (or any other C# ADO.NET object) without looping through all the items?  I have a query that is returning a single column, and I want to put that into a string array (or ArrayList, or List, etc).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is possible. In .NET 2.0+, `SqlDataReader` inherits from `DbDataReader`, which implements `IEnumerable` (non-generic one). This means that you can use LINQ:

```
List<string> list = (from IDataRecord r in dataReader
                     select (string)r["FieldName"]
                    ).ToList();
```

That said, the loop is still there, it's just hidden in `Enumerable.Select`, rather than being explicit in your code.

Comment: There are masters here. Nice answer.

Comment: how do I display the list values to the console.

Comment: shawn, foreach + Console.WriteLine.

Comment: can you give small sample of code?  foreach( r in reader) {Console.writeline(list[I].tostring()  } don't work can you show how the foreach is accessing the list and what are you comparing it to

Comment: `foreach (var row in reader) Console.WriteLine(row["FieldName"])`

Comment: I got it to work but now I'm trying to add another list for another field column how would I include another list array for another column field with the reader?

Comment: You cannot generate two lists in one pass, but you shouldn't be trying to. Instead of two lists of strings, use a single list - either of anonymous class instances (you'll need to use `var` to declare the variable in that case, since there's no way to describe the type), or of Tuple instances, or of your own struct/class. Anonymous classes are usually easiest, e.g.: 

`var list = (from IDataRecord r in dataReader select new { FieldName1 = (string)r["FieldName1"], FieldName2 = (string)r["FieldName2"] }).ToList();`

Comment: @PavelMinaev what would this code look like in regular LINQ syntax rather than query syntax?

Comment: `dataReader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(r => (string)r["FieldName"]).ToList()`

Comment: make sure referencing `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 15):

No, since `SqlDataReader` is a forward-only read-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database, the stream of rows will be looped through whether explicitly in your code or hidden in a framework implementation (such as DataTable's `Load` method).

It sounds like using a generic list and then returning the list as an array would be a good option. For example,

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
    }    
}
return list.ToArray();
```

In response to your comment, calling ToArray() may be overhead, it depends. Do you need an array of objects to work with or would a generic collection (such as `List<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`) be more useful?

Comment: Do you think that TaArray() method is just more overhead?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, ever since .NET 1.1 `SqlDataReader` had [the following method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int size;
object[] data = new object[]{};
size = reader.GetValues(data);
```

This populates `data` with the values of the current reader row, assigning into size the number of objects that were put into the array.

Comment: Size your array to have the datas

`object[] data = new object[reader.FieldCount];`

Answer (score 5):

Since any `IDataReader` implementation (`SqlDataReader` included) will be a forward-only reader by definition, no there is no way to do this without looping.  Even if there were a framework library method to do this it would have to loop through the reader, just like you would.

Answer (score 1):

The orignial OP asked for Array, ArrayList or List. You can return Array as well. Just call the .ToArray() method and assign it to a previously declared array.  Arrays are very fast when it comes to enumerating each element.  Much faster than a List if the list has more than 1000 elements. 
You can return to Array, List, or Dictionary.

```
ids_array = (from IDataRecord r in idReader 
select (string)r["ID"]).ToArray<string>();
```

Additionally, if you are using a lookup of keys for example, you might consider creating a HashSet object with has excellent lookup performance if you are simply checking one list against another to determine if an elements key exists in the HashSet object.
example:

```
 HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>( 
(from IDataRecord r in idReader select (string)r["ID"]).AsEnumerable<string>() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop, but there are projects that can make it simpler.  Also, try not to use ArrayList, use List instead.

You can checkout FluentAdo for one:  http://fluentado.codeplex.com

```
    public IList<UserAccount> List()
    {
        var list = new FluentCommand<UserAccount>("SELECT ID, UserName, Password FROM UserAccount")
            .SetMap(reader => new UserAccount
            {
                ID = reader.GetInt("ID"),
                Password = reader.GetString("Password"),
                UserName = reader.GetString("UserName"),
            })
            .AsList();

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read your SqlDataAdapter into a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt as DataTable; 
dt.fill(data);
```

Then you can use some of the toys in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` as referenced in Joel Muller's answer to this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762000/filer-datatable-to-exclude-dbnull-value)

In uses a bit of Linq, so you will net .Net 3.5 or higher.

Answer (score -2):

```
var array = reader.GetValue("field_name") as long[];
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.