# Adding more than one column to a C# list from MySQL Select

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to put a MySQL select into a List.  I found one piece of code that works, however I need to add more than one column.  I want to return an array of all the data in the select.

```
List<string> list = (from IDataRecord r in dataReader
                     select (string)r["FieldName"]
                    ).ToList();
```

Code was found here:
[Fill an array (or arraylist) from SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370543/fill-an-array-or-arraylist-from-sqldatareader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var list = (from IDataRecord r in dataReader
            select new 
                   {
                        Field1 = (string)r["Field1"],
                        Field2 = (int)r["Field2"],
                         ...
                   }
            ).ToList();
```

Just add fields as needed.

Comment: It seems I have having an issue with that, I was unable to use var list, so I tried List<String> and sense the data types are not all String it throws a fit.  Im guessing i need to do something such as IEnumerable, but im not sure how..  The exactly error I get with the List<String> is Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'  it doesn't like the .ToList()

Comment: I got it figured out now.. Thanks!