# C# - Convert SqlDataReader to ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, arraylist

Is there a way to convert SqlDataReader to arrayList?

I have to pass the results of a query from one page to another so that I can then bind it to a gridview.  However, I can't pass the SqlDataReader object in the session.

How can I achieve the following?:

```
if (rdr.HasRows == true)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                             arraylist.add(whole row); //pseudo code
                        }
                    }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I would fill a `DataTable` with a `SqlDataAdapter` and use that as `DataSource`.

Comment: Why would you want to use `ArrayList` rather than a `List<T>`?

Comment: May be duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370543/fill-an-array-or-arraylist-from-sqldatareader

Comment: I don't know.  I thought that an arraylist would do the job hehe :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a SqlDataReader to build a DataTable and pass this object

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (rdr.HasRows == true)
     dt.Load(rdr);
```

A very complete  example with various options available could be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx)
Now you could pass the whole DataTable instance and use it to bind the GridView