# how to store values data reader values from database into an array? vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Is there a way to store data from a sql data reader values to an array?

this is my code

```
 Dim machines() As Integer
Sub machine_entire()
    Try
        'getting lines from the database
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "select machineID from tbl_prod_machine where lineID = '" & lineID & "' order by machineID asc"
        End With
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                machines = {dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("machineID"))}
            End While
            dr.Close()
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As DataException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Sql Server Error # " & ex.Number & ": " & ex.GetType.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

thank you! for the help

Comment: If you used a DataTable, you could just use the values from that handy container.  Or you could use a List(of Integer) and fill it without having to know how many things there are ahead of time.  An array is a bad choice for this: the DR cant tell you how many rows there are, so you cant know how big to make the array.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use FieldCount and Item(Int32). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_properties(v=vs.110).aspx. This gets you an array of column values, which is probably not what you want, according to above code. What do you expect as a result of this command? `machines = {dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("machineID"))}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370543/fill-an-array-or-arraylist-from-sqldatareader

Its C# code but might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a list of integer, I would use a List(Of )

```
Dim machines As New List(Of Integer)
```

After than you just add the values to the list

```
machines.Add(dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("machineID")))
```

Side note, I would rename your function and make it return the list. In this context, lineId and machines do not seem a good idea to be outside of the function.

```
Function GetMachineIdsFromLine(ByVal lineId) As List(Of Integer)
```

Also, it is recomended to open connection only when needed and close them as soon as possible.