# Convert SQLite select query to string array

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have this code

```
public static void GetOnline1()
        {
            string query = "SELECT online FROM online";
            SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader result = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (result.HasRows)
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result["online"]);
                    //result["online"] to string array?
                }
            }
            myConnection.Close();
```

How i can convert result["online"] to a string array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill an array (or arraylist) from SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370543/fill-an-array-or-arraylist-from-sqldatareader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the results in a `List<string>`:

```
var onlineList = new List<string>();
if (result.HasRows)
{
    while (result.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result["online"]);
        onlineList.Add(result["online"].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you need it as an array, you can use this: `onlineList.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new list of string before `if(result.HasRows)`.

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

And then add `result["online"]` to list in while loop as following.

```
while(result.Read())
{
     list.Add(result["online"].ToString());
}
```