# How can read db table column data one by one using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to retrieve data from db table column one by one.

```
Suppose, I have this table:
**Column_Name=Name**
Mark
David
Bob
Bond
Smith
```

I am using this code to retrive data one by one form db table column.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Odisha1ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        String query = "select Name from Customer";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            string Col0 = dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            //string Col1 = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            //string Col2 = dataReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            //string Col3 = dataReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            //string Col4 = dataReader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            Response.Write("col0="col0);
        }
```

But using this code, all data is coming in one row.I am getting output like this:

```
MarkDavidBobBondSmith
```

I want to assign all data one by one in string.I like to get output like this as i am using in my code above.

```
col0 = Mark
col1 = David
col2 = Bob
col3 = Bond
col4 = Smith
```

Comment: If you wrote the output to a string file all you'd have to do is add a newline after each string. In HTML though newlines are ignored. This has *almost* nothing to do with how you read the data - you can use `dateReader.FieldCount` in a loop to write each column value to the response, eg `for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++){ var value=dataReader.GetValue(0); Response.Write("col{0} = {1}",i,value);}`

Comment: The code inside the `{` brackets of the while loop will run once for each of the five rows in your table so perhaps you'd be better off adding them to a list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370592/825093. The reason there are no spaces is because you need to have a newline character at the end of the string you use in your Response.Write call.

Comment: @silleknarf I also want to store each value in different string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a counter like following:

```
int count = 0;    
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    string Col = dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    Response.Write("col"+ count +" = "+ Col + "<br />");
    count++;
}
```

**Update:**

Added `</br>` at end of the text.

Comment: I also want to store each data(value) in different string.

Comment: @scoop Instead of storing in different variables you should use `Array` of type `String`. If you want code I can update the answer.

Comment: no need ..I have done by using array. Thanks for reply.